# Problem with Mutiple CSV Data Set config in jmeter

Tags: csv, http, while-loop, jmeter, performance-testing

Below is my Test plan to read Data from Multiple CSV file. I wants to test Scenario like
1. 10 users performed operation on 100 documents. Idealy each user should get 10 documents and perfromed the operation on it.

TestPlan 
Thread Group
    While controller
        LoginUserDataConfig
        LoginRequestRecordingController
            HTTPLoginRequest
        DocumentOperationRecordingController
                DocIDList
                HttpSaveRequest

But with above plan It is taking only 10 document and stop the process. I run the script by changing CSVDataConfigu setting like Shared Mode to All Thread\Current Thread but not getting desired output.
Can any one correct my test plan.

Thread Settings:

```
 Number of Thread: 10
 Ramp-Up Period: 2
 loop count: 1
```

LoginUserDataConfig Settings:

```
 Allowed Quoted Data: False
 Recycle on EOF? False
 Stop Thread on EOF: True
 Sharing mode: Current Thread Group
```

DocIDList Settings:

```
 Allowed Quoted Data: False
 Recycle on EOF? False
 Stop Thread on EOF: True
 Sharing mode: Current Thread Group
```

Answer (score 0):

You should mark loop count as forever and it will continue until **E**nd **O**f **F**ile of CSV (100 IDs)

Comment: Still same results after changing the loop count to forever.

Comment: @dingo you need to remove `While controller` it's unneeded